# Select variable key in ngFor loop

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have 2 nested ngFor loops.
The first

```
<ion-item-group *ngFor="let team of shift.teams_assigned">
```

Defines team and I would like to use team as a selector for a child loop like this

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let member of shift.members_assigned.team">
```

Is there a specific syntax to access the key of an array like members_assigned.**$_variable_key_i_want_to_loop**

Comment: is team an array .?

Comment: yes team is an array

Comment: what is the issue now.?

Comment: I seem to have trouble wording my question. My issue is that this ngFor loop is inside another ngFor loop which specifies the team to be selected from the teams array. So the second loop would need to reference the current team in the first loop

Comment: Post the full code

Comment: I agree with @Stefan if you use the value of the first NgFor in the second NgFor you must have the team that is running in the first 'cycle' For :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do it like that if I well understand your question because it is not clear to me

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let team of shift.teams_assigned">
   <ion-item *ngFor="let member of team">
   </ion-item>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: I agree with @Stefan if you use the value of the first NgFor in the second NgFor you must have the team that is running in the first 'cycle' For :-)

Comment: Thank you for reading, understanding and solving my question, I had trouble wording this issue.